# URI formatting URL

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5

All

I have the the following lines of code... (.net 3.5)

```
string URL = "http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/url=http%3a%2f%2fuk.linkedin.com%2fpub%2fjulian-welby-everard%2f0%2fb97%2f416";
UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder(URL);
```

this returns a URL in the URI object of  http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/url=http://uk.linkedin.com/pub/julian-welby-everard/0/b97/416 which as been decoded, I do not what this to happen

so I tried to encoded the data twice giving

```
string URL = "http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/url=http%253a%252f%252fuk.linkedin.com%252fpub%252fjulian-welby-everard%252f0%252fb97%252f416";
UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder(URL);
```

this now returns the URL as follows http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/url=http%253a%252f%252fuk.linkedin.com%252fpub%252fjulian-welby-everard%252f0%252fb97%252f416 note that it has not decoded anything this time, i was hoping that it would decode just like the first attempt but as this had been double encoded it would return the string in the correct format.

So the question is as follows, I can I stop the URI object from decoding the supplied URL so I can pass the correct data accross to the HttpWebRequest.

Julian

Comment: Isn't this what you are looking for: `Uri uri = new Uri(URL);` instead of UriBuilder?

Comment: Tried that it still decodes the URL when its is created, which is what i am trying to stop

Comment: What is exactly the url you expect to query ?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. Julian have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for HttpUtility.UrlEncode("http://www.google.com/") which returns http%3a%2f%2fwww.google.com%2f.

Comment: That I have tried, the problem is that the UriBuilder is UrlDecoding the string, which is what i want to stop as i need to send the string as is.